# Question on Doubling sequence and diagonal principle

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Assume  $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence converging to $x$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists another sequence $(x_{n,m})_{m}$ converging
to $x_n.$

> Question 1 Can we say that $(x_{n,n})_n$ converges to $x$? If not, for what additional condition does $(x_{n,n})_n$ converges to $x$?

Now assume $(x_{n,m})_{n,m}$ be a doubling sequence such that

for every fixed $n$ $(x_{n,m})_{m}$ converges to $x_n$ and the sequence $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$.

> Question 2 Can we say that, $(x_{n,n})_{n}$ converges to $x$?

**Roughly speaking** what are the suitable assumptions for which Diagonal principle apply?

Answer (score 1):

Take $x_n=1$ for all $n$ and $x_{n,m}=\begin{cases}1& m\ne n\\0&m=n\end{cases}$.

I think this provide a negative answer to both questions.

Comment: This looks correct to me. Not sure why it was downvoted.